# How can i get the color with given name firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

can somebody help me with the valueeventlstener?

i have got this database structure in firebase

```
Categories
    -KvxSVFRZIO3ENylF0id
        color: "ff99ffff"
        name: "Cars"
    -KvxbiS-L6iALA7Os8q4
        color: "fffffdd4"
        name: "Movies"
```

now i want to get fffffdd4 in a string when the name Movies is given.

```
mkatcolordb.child("Categories").orderByChild("name").equalTo(item).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String areaName = dataSnapshot.child("color").getValue(String.class);
        StyleableToast.makeText(NewThemaActivity.this, areaName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG, R.style.StyledToast).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

This code doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code needs to handle this. The simplest way to do so for your code:

```
mkatcolordb.child("Categories").orderByChild("name").equalTo(item).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot colorSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String areaName = colorSnapshot.child("color").getValue(String.class);
        StyleableToast.makeText(NewThemaActivity.this, areaName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG, R.style.StyledToast).show();
      }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```